# Hash navigation and static iframes

Tags: html, iframe

I encountered an issue playing with iframes that I don't really know how to explain.

I want to inject some HTML into an iframe, and then navigate within this injected HTML through `<a>` tags.

The issue is that, since the iframe is contained in an `overflow: hidden;` container (and that's what I don't understand), the iframe slides vertically when I click the link, while the target link is already into view.

The HTML injection is done with basic js:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
var frameDoc = iframe.document;
if (iframe.contentWindow) {
    frameDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
}
frameDoc.open();
var sContent = "<!doctype html>";
sContent += "<head>";
sContent += "</head>";
sContent += "<body>";
sContent += "<a id='myLink'></a>";
sContent += "<a id='myButton' href='#myLink'>Click me</a>";
sContent += "</body>";
frameDoc.write(sContent);
frameDoc.close();
```

Does anyone see what I am missing, or what I could do to get the proper behaviour, aka have the iframe stay in place when I navigate ?

A running example can be found on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7bRF/1/).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sContent += '';

must be:
sContent += '';

Struggling with the same problem..
(Think it's a bug, 
 have also tried: sContent += "'** id='myButton' href='#myLink'>Click me" 
 still don't works.. .)